# How to fetch accurate city information from client IP in India?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, google-geocoder

I am working on Rails app with Angular JS as front end. Tried using Geocoder for fetching city information using Rails gem as well as JS integration with paid Geocoder account. It doesn't work accurately and fails at times.

Please suggest some tools to fetch accurate city information from IP.

Comment: Have a look at GeoIP. Here is the link to its ruby library https://github.com/cjheath/geoip

Comment: Tried geoip. It is showing Mumbai for an IP address of Chandigarh. I need a stable tool for my web app.

Comment: You shall probably need an updated GeoIP DB(most probably the paid one ) for best results. Otherwise best of luck finding it (y)